# Kraken2 Standard Database failing to build (unexpected FTP path)

Tags: ngs, metagenome, ncbi

I am attempting to build just the standard Kraken2 Database by using the following command:

```
kraken2-build --standard --threads 24 --db $DBNAME
```

I am returned the following error a few minutes building it:

```
rsync_from_ncbi.pl: unexpected FTP path (new server?) for 
https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCF/000/762/265/GCF_000762265.1_ASM76226v1
```

Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same issue yesterday and after trying the `--use-ftp` argument without luck (this is proposed as an alternative in the forums), I have downloaded the database from [Kraken 2, KrakenUniq and Bracken indexes](https://benlangmead.github.io/aws-indexes/k2) ([ref](https://github.com/DerrickWood/kraken2/issues/753#issuecomment-1692288857)).